# Applinking in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have developed a browser(Xamarin App) named "MyBrowser" and now what I want is if a user clicks on any link it should open up a list of browsers (along with "MyBrowser") available for the user.

Once the user selects "MyBrowser", from there it should open the link in "MyBrowser".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, does the user click links on some other application like Chrome, Safari etc? It's easier to get help when describing the issue with more detail and specifying what you've already tried (and what went wrong).

Comment: What I know is one way to salve it is deep linking where you mention intent filters like THIS : <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly you'd now want that to work for all links instead of just ones starting with `gizmos`?

Comment: Yes you got that correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to catch all the web URLs such as the ones that start with http:// and https://, you can certainly do it on Android but on iOS it's not possible. I'll present a minimal example of how to catch the URL in your application, that should be a good starting point for you to move forward.

### Android

On Android, you first need to decorate your main Activity with the IntentFilter attribute that defines the actions, categories and data schemes to utilize (this is basically the same as what you pasted to the comment section but in C#):

```cs
[Activity(Label = "UrlSample", MainLauncher = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, 
    DataSchemes = new[] { "http", "https" })]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
...
```

While the app is compiled, these attributes are parsed and inserted into the final AndroidManifest.xml file. For more information about the process and an example of this, take a look at Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest#intent-actions-and-features).

Now, you can check in the OnCreate method of MainActivity.cs, whether the app was launched via an appropriate Intent. MessageCenter will notify all the subscribers about an event called *new_url* (naming is up to you) with an instance of UrlMessage class as the payload and the Url set to a property within that class:

```cs
if (Intent != null && Intent.Action == Intent.ActionView)
{
    Uri data = Intent.Data;
    /* Get the full url with for example data.ToString() call and do whatever you want with it */
}
```

---

### iOS

Unfortunately, Apple is not as permissive with the URL schemes as Android. In the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app), they state the following:

> You cannot claim support for some well-known URL schemes, including http, https, mailto, tel, sms, facetime, and facetime-audio. The system directs well-known types of URLs to the corresponding system apps and well-known http–based URLs to specific apps, such as Maps, YouTube, and Music.